# Sessions with new facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-login

I want to launch a new activity after successfully logging in using facebook login and maintain my session across all activities. I also don't want the log out in the next screen.

Samples for the new sdk don't provide any info about sessions so I am not sure how to go about this. Do we use `AccessToken` or `Session` class to maintain session and could anyone please provide links or examples for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "maintain my session across all activities"?

Comment: maintain "logged in" status after having logged in??

Comment: Once you initialize the Facebook SDK in your app and go through the login steps and get the access token, your application will be logged in until you use code to logout.

Comment: And you can fetch the access token (once the user logged in via your app) from any of your activities via AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); which is a static function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you initialize the Facebook SDK in your app and go through the login steps and get the user access token, your application will be logged in until you logout from user account via code.

And you can fetch the access token and check its status and validity (once the user logged in via your app) from any of your application activities via:

```
mAccessToken =AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); // Which is a static function. 

if(mAccessToken == null) // user are not logged in
  {
     // Proceed with your log in logic / code.
  }
```

Comment: The access token is available like you said. However, when I resume the application from the home screen or another application, I am redirected to the login screen with a log out button and not my post login screen/activity. How do I get around this?

Comment: Mostly that's because in your code (Which I don't have / aware of) you are asking the user to login again, which leads to open the login screen with a log out button, you should check if your application is logged in or not before applying the login code.